# Android - HTML ImageParser align center

Tags: android, html

I want to create a News App and now, my app displays posts from Json with Html Parser.

Images from HTML content was display with an ImageParser but was not align center. I need help to do this.

This is my code:

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(json_data.getString("contenu"), this, null);
description_projet.setText(spanned);



 @Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

    new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

    return d;
}

class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String source = (String) params[0];
        mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + source);
        try {
            InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            mDrawable.setLevel(1);
            CharSequence t = description_projet.getText();
            description_projet.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This ImageParser update my Textview with images. I want only my images align center and not all my TextView. I think that gravity center on my TextView will center text too.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.fromHtml()` will create `ImageSpan`s so you can just apply `AlignmentSpan`s at the same points in the result:

```
@NonNull
public static Spanned centerImageSpans(@NonNull Spanned sp) {
    ImageSpan[] imageSpans = sp.getSpans(0, sp.length(), ImageSpan.class);
    if (imageSpans == null || imageSpans.length == 0) {
        return sp;
    }
    SpannableString result = new SpannableString(sp);
    for (ImageSpan imageSpan : imageSpans) {
        AlignmentSpan alignSpan = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
        int start = result.getSpanStart(imageSpan);
        int end = result.getSpanEnd(imageSpan);
        result.setSpan(alignSpan, start, end, 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```